# Having trouble compiling BFLT Utils: can't find libiberty.h, despite being installed

Tags: linux, debian, compiling, make

I'm attempting compile BFLT Utils (https://github.com/nihilus/bflt-utils), but keep getting the following error:

```
$:/tmp/bflt-utils/flthdr# make
gcc -Wall -g -O2 compress.c -c
gcc -Wall -g -O2 stubs.c -c
gcc -Wall -g -O2 flthdr.c -c
flthdr.c:22:23: fatal error: libiberty.h: No such file or directory
     #include <libiberty.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'flthdr.o' failed
make: *** [flthdr.o] Error 1
```

I have installed `libiberty-dev` using `apt-get install libiberty-dev`. And using `find / -name libiberty.*` yields:

```
/usr/include/libiberty/libiberty.h
```

I have attempted to modify the Makefile to add the path using:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O2 -L/usr/include/libiberty
LDFLAGS=-lz -lc -lbfd -liberty
TARGET=flthdr

$(TARGET): compress.o stubs.o flthdr.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) *.o $(LDFLAGS)

compress.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) compress.c -c

stubs.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) stubs.c -c

flthdr.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) flthdr.c -c

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(TARGET)
```

But I still get the same error.

Why is the header file not being found?

Comment: Try `-I/usr/include/libiberty` instead of `-L/usr/include/libiberty` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark's comment above is correct: Your `CFLAGS` addition should use `-I`, not `-L`. The `-L` flag to the compiler tells it where to find libraries, but you're failing to find a [*header* file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) instead.

(Yes, the header file is called `libiberty.h`, but that doesn't make it a library.)

Generally you use `-L` flags in makefiles in `LDFLAGS` and related variables.

(I've [reported this issue](https://github.com/nihilus/bflt-utils/issues/1) to the project, so hopefully it won't bite anyone else, once fixed. Maybe you will provide a patch or pull request, Torra.)